# Input file not transferring data when it's disabled

Tags: php, jquery, html

In my project I am disabling an Input file after loading files. When I submit the form, I can not retrieve the files that I have pass. In the opposite direction, once I activate the input, the files reappear.

```
$('input[name="files[]"]').attr('disabled',true)
```

I want to know if there is a way to resolve this issue.

```
'files' => 
array (size=5)
  'name' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '3.jpg' (length=5)
      1 => string '2.jpg' (length=5)
      2 => string '1.jpg' (length=5)
  'type' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
      1 => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
      2 => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
  'tmp_name' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '/tmp/phptPZXzB' (length=14)
      1 => string '/tmp/phpGgGVuT' (length=14)
      2 => string '/tmp/phpFQdZpb' (length=14)
  'error' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => int 0
      1 => int 0
      2 => int 0
  'size' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => int 152903
      1 => int 154259
      2 => int 137271
```

Answer (score 1):

Use readonly attribute instead of disabled : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp

Comment: it is an input file, not a text one per example.

Comment: My bad, then you have 2 solutions : remove the disabled attribute in js before you submit the form, that way your input will be sent ; or create an hidden input with your files.

Comment: I opt for the first solution